# Why does my homepage sometimes shows up in black and white text?

Tags: homepage

I do not know why my WordPress website (i.e., the homepage) sometimes shows up in black and white text? This is not what I want.

[image: Not the way the website is supposed to look.]

Other times, the homepage shows up correctly.
[image: The way the website is supposed to look]

I have attached images.

I would appreciate any help with this.

The website is http://asclsoregon.org/

Comment: Because your stylesheet is failing to load. At first glance this happens when you load the site over HTTPS, and works OK when you load over HTTP. It looks like the site you're loading the content from, `https://box5705.temp.domains/~asclsore/` does not have a valid SSL certificate and does not have the content to server when requested over HTTPS anyway. You can probably see this in your browser's debug tools: look for a network tab or similar and you'll see all the requests failing.

Comment: If it's not HTTP vs HTTPS, i.e. you're seeing the failure for HTTP too, then again try and reproduce this with your browser's debug tools open to see what that the error code and error messages are for the stylesheet load failures. You can probably get some information from your server's access logs too.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.